# This project has reached its maximum number of OAuth clients

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform

Once a project has reached its maximum number of OAuth clients can we add more google script codes to the project by creating Service Accounts for the project? 
Or is there some way of overcoming this maximum number of OAuth clients?

Comment: Why are you creating multiple clients? You only need one, or maybe one per application. You can also use multiple projects.

Comment: @John. Thanks!! Creating multiple projects solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This limit is probably related to your [app being unverified](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/7454865).

If you haven't already, try to [request verification for your app](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/7454865#verification) and follow the verification process.

Comment: But while going through the documentation suggested by you I have seen the following-. Verification is not required for Apps Script projects whose owner and users belong to the same G Suite domain or customer.

Comment: @superadmin didn't notice that your project was Apps Script. I don't really know much about that product, sorry.